# Hive : join 2 tables and select different columns in single query

Tags: hive

I have two tables in hive say Table A and Table B. Basically i want to join both of them and want to select the different column based on some condition in single query .

*Table A:*

```
empid;name;sal;dept

1;'X';100;IT

2;'Y';100;IT

3;'Z';100;ADMIN
```

*Table B:*

```
empid;name;address

1;'X';A

2;'Y';B

3;'Z';C
```

Desired output:

```
When Dept='IT'
select empid,name,address from Table A join Table B on (A.empid=B.empid)

When Dept='ADMIN'
select empid,address from Table A join Table B on (A.empid=B.empid)
```

Can someone please help me with the approach?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a single query, the output has to be in the same structure. 
I assume you don't want to show the name of the ADMIN due to some security reasons.

If so, you could do the below instead. Admin's names will be shown as 'Name not available'. Hope this helps. If not, please tell us the reason behind your question.

```
SELECT ta.empid, 
       CASE WHEN ta.dept = 'IT' THEN ta.name
            WHEN ta.dept = 'ADMIN' THEN 'Name not available'
       END AS name,
       tb.address
  FROM tableA ta,
       tableB tb
WHERE ta.empid = tb.empid;
```